# Cakephp bindModel not working

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to bind Company hasMany CompanyReview. Below are the code in the controller:

```
public function review() {
    $this->uses = array('Search', 'Company', 'CompanyReview');
    $this->Company->bindModel(array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'CompanyReview' => array(
            'className' => 'CompanyReview',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id'
            )
        )
    ));
    $this->CompanyReview->bindModel(
        array(
           'belongsTo'=>array(
                'Company'=>array(
                    'className'=>'Company',
                    'foreignKey'=>'company_id'
                 )
            )
        )
    );

    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        switch ($this->data['Search']['search_type']) {
            case 'all':
                $this->request->data['ReviewResults'] = $this->allReviews($this->data['Search']['search_query']);
                break;
            case 'company':
                $this->request->data = $this->Company->find('all', array(
                   'conditions' => array(
                      'OR' => array(
                          'MATCH(Company.name) against ("' . $this->data['Search']['search_query'] . '" in boolean mode)',
                          'MATCH(CompanyReview.job_title) against ("' . $this->data['Search']['search_query'] . '" in boolean mode)'
                           )

                        )
                    ));
                break;
            case 'interview':
                $this->request->data['ReviewResults'] = $this->interviewReviews($this->data['Search']['search_query']);
                break;
            case 'salary':
                $this->request->data['ReviewResults'] = $this->salaryReviews($this->data['Search']['search_query']);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

but the error I keep getting is:Database Error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CompanyReview.job_title' in 'where clause'
```

**SQL Query**: 
`SELECT Company.id, Company.name, Company.industry_id, Company.website, Company.created FROM terbang2.companies AS Company WHERE ((MATCH(Company.name) against ("air" in boolean mode)) OR (MATCH(CompanyReview.job_title) against ("air" in boolean mode)))`

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create **app/View/Errors/pdo_error.ctp**

if you noticed, the sql did not include company_reviews table. How is it so? Please help!. Thanks

Oh and btw,there is a table row called job_title in the company_reviews table.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [[Joins]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).

"Normal" queries that are auto-built from associations actually do separate queries for each model, therefore you cannot refer to fields that don't exist in their table, and will result in an error (like the one you're getting) if tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you want cake automagic to work use `$this->CompanyReview->find();` because cake does joins only in case of `$belongsTo` and `$hasOne`. In `$hasMany` and HABTM there are separate queries. If you want / need to do find on Company, you need to do joins mentioned by @Dave.

Note.
You do not need to bind both ways. If you do find on Company, then bind only to Company model.